# What are the best practices to parse data into objects in data access layer?

Tags: c#, n-tier-architecture

I am adding new features to an old asp.net application which uses n-tier architecture. A basic example can be given as

**Object**

```
public class Test
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public int name{get;set;}
}
```

**Data Access Layer**

```
public static List<Test> GetTests()
{
    List<Test> list = new List<Test>();
    try
    {
        //codes
        SqlDataReader dr  = com.ExecuteReader();
        while(dr.Read())
            list.Add(FillTestRecord(dr))
        //codes
    }
    catch{}
    return list;
}

private static Test FillTestRecord(IDataRecord dr)
{
    Test test = new Test();
    try{test.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);}
    catch{}
    try{test.Name = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Name"]);}
    catch{}
    return test;
}
```

The development requires me to add new fields to object classes and for re-usability i use only one Fill*Record Method for each type of object. This method can be called by many other DAL methods whose IDataRecord might not contain all the columns of the object. Hence I put try-catch block for every property separately. This ensures that all the available columns in IDataRecord are parsed properly.

My question is that is there any better way of doing it? And what are the best practices in this type of architecture?

### UPDATE

After reading the comment/answer of David L and Anup I have tried another way to do it using Extension Method. The method is as follows

```
public static bool TryGetOrdinal(this IDataRecord dr, string column, out int ordinal)
{
    try
    {
        ordinal = dr.GetOrdinal(column);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ordinal = -1; //Just setting a value that GetOrdinal doesn't return
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

so the `FillTestRecord` method will be

```
private static Test FillTestRecord(IDataRecord dr)
{
    Test test = new Test();

    int ordinal = default(int);

    if(dr.TryGetOrdinal("ID",out ordinal))
        test.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(ordinal));
    if(dr.TryGetOrdinal("Name",out ordinal))
        test.Name = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(ordinal));

    return test;
}
```

any suggestion on this is highly appreciated.

### UPDATE 03-02-2016

during debugging i found that the `try-catch` takes a big toll on performance if `GetOrdinal` throws error when the supplied column name is not found in the `DataRecord`. So I wrote a new method that gets the column names in the `DataReader` and replaced `GetOrdinal` with `Array.IndexOf`.

```
public static bool TryGetOrdinal(this IDataRecord dr, string[] columnNames, string column, out int ordinal)
{
    ordinal = Array.IndexOf(columnNames, column);
    return ordinal >= 0;
}
```

And my `FillTestRecord` becomes -

```
private static Test FillTestRecord(IDataRecord dr, string[] columnNames)
{
    Test test = new Test();

    int ordinal = default(int);

    if(dr.TryGetOrdinal(columnNames, "id",out ordinal))
        test.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(ordinal));
    if(dr.TryGetOrdinal(columnNames, "name",out ordinal))
        test.Name = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(ordinal));

    return test;
}
```

column names are passed to Fill method like this -

```
using (var dr = com.ExecuteReader())
{
    string[] colNames = dr.GetColumnNames();
    while (dr.Read())
        list.Add(FillTestRecord(dr, colNames));
}
```

'GetColumnNames' is the new extension method -

```
public static string[] GetColumnNames(this IDataReader dr)
{
    string[] columnNames = new string[dr.FieldCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        columnNames[i] = dr.GetName(i).ToLower();
    }
    return columnNames;
}
```

Comment: You're basically trying to reinvent the Wheel. Use Entity Framework instead.

Comment: If you are catching, consume the exception in a useful manner.  Empty catches are heavily frowned upon.

Comment: @HighCore, if I use Entity Framework then I have to do a lot of recode, which is not a viable option at the moment.

Comment: I agree with @DavidL The empty exceptions are suggesting it is not really an error and should be handled in a different way. I suggest checking - before acting, rather acting and than asking for forgiveness...

Comment: problem is that i can't find a good way to check whether a column exist in the DataRecord. for example, `dr.GetOrdinal(string columnname)` also throws exception if it can't find the column in the DataRow

Comment: @th1rdey3 how about the `HasColumn`metod I have posted?

Comment: Your `HasColumn` method is also a good idea. It removes the need of exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you are in the right direction.
As long as the parsing is being done in a centralized location which is re-used by all upper level classes, this is looks like a good solution.

The only thing I would change is replacing the `try-catch` statements with checking if the data exists in the columns. surely there is a way to tell (column does not exist? DB-Null value?)
You could implement that using a something similar to the [TryParse methods](http://www.fatagnus.com/why-you-should-use-tryparse-in-c/).

```
    private static Test FillTestRecord(IDataRecord dr)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        int tempId;
        if (TryParseDataRow<int>(dr, "ID", out tempId))
        {
            test.Id = tempId;
        }
        return test;
    }

    private static bool TryParseDataRow<T>(IDataRecord record, string column, out T value)
    {
        value = default(T);
        bool success = true;

        if (record == null)
        {
            //nothing you can do with a null object
            success = false;
        }
        else if (!record.HasColumn(column)) //not sure if this will throw exeption or return null. you can check in your project
        {
            success = false;
        }
        else if (record[column] != typeof(T))
        {
            //object was of an unexpected type
            success = false;
        }           
        else
        {
            //cast the value into the output parameter
            value = (T)record[column];
        }

        return success;
    }
```

And of course you will have to implement the `HasColumn` method (Implemented here as extension):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified record has column.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="record">The record.</param>
    /// <param name="columnName">Name of the column.</param>
    /// <returns>true if column exist, false otherwise</returns>
    public static bool HasColumn(this IDataRecord record, string columnName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < record.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (record.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: if there is no `"ID"` named column in the returned DataRecord then dr["ID"] will give `index out of range error`. so if i follow your solution it will still give an error at `if (TryParseDataRow<int>(dr["ID"], out tempId))`

Comment: I think `(obj.GetType() != typeof(T))` will always return true as `obj/record` will not be `typeof(T)`. Also `record[colum]` will throw exception if the column doesn't exist in record.

Comment: yup, thats what you get when you have code you can't run and test... Any way answer was modified.

Comment: I have tried something else, updated my question, let me know what you think.

Comment: @th1rdey3 It looks good. In your proposal you still have exceptions thrown, but you handle them locally. this is much better then your original proposal of an empty catch clause. In my proposal I have avoided exceptions completely. on the other hand if the datatype in the db will change, lets say from int to decimal, you will get an exception rather then en empty field. which is actually good...

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I put together for mapping IDataRecord's to properties

```
    public static T ParseRecord<T>(this IDataRecord reader) where T : new()
    {
        var model = new T();
        var type = typeof(T);

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
            var fieldType = reader.GetFieldType(i);
            var fieldName = reader.GetName(i);
            var val = reader.GetValue(i);
            var prop = type.GetProperty(fieldName);

            // handle or throw instead here if needed
            if (prop == null)
                continue;

            var propType = prop.PropertyType;

            // HACK: remove this if you don't want to coerce to strings
            if (propType == typeof(string))
                prop.SetValue(model, val.ToString());
            else if (fieldType != propType)
                throw new Exception($"Type mismatch field {fieldType} != prop {propType}");
            else
                prop.SetValue(model, val);
        }

        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to map properties of different objects. It uses reflection to get the properties of the source and target objects, but you can easily change it to work with IDataRecord:

```
public static T MapDTO<T>(object dto) where T : new()
{
    T Result = new T();

    if (dto == null)
        return Result;

    dto.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(p =>
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = Result.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name);

            if (prop != null && prop.CanWrite)
            {
                try
                {
                    var convertedVal = Convert.ChangeType(p.GetValue(dto, null), prop.PropertyType);
                    prop.SetValue(Result, convertedVal, null);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(Result, p.GetValue(dto, null), null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex1) { }
                }
            }
        });
    return Result;
}
```

The key here is that the source and dest properties should have same names.